# Excel macro to remove rows that have been added via another macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have recently added a macro to add a selection from Sheets("Activities") and insert it into a new row positioned at row 25 on Sheets("EP2"). - Thus adding new pre-written "activities" into the sheet.

There are a number of different selections (pre-written activities) from Sheets("Activities") that have been assigned their own buttons.

When the button is pressed, the appropriate selection from Sheets("Activities") is inserted into the same position (row 25 on Sheets("EP2"))

This means that each time another activity is added, the last addition moves down the page. This is all fine.

HOWEVER, I am wanting to add coinciding buttons to then remove certain activities (from Sheets("EP2") at a later date. this poses a problem because when a certain activity is added to the sheet it may not have the same cell reference as when it was 1st added via the macro. Is there a way around this?

Basically, this form has to be for people that have almost no understanding of excel whatsoever and needs to have these prewritten activities add-able at a click of a button and then removable at the click of a button. The code I am using is as follows..

```
Sub Insert_CV()

Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult

Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to insert a CV agreement" & vbNewLine & "This cannot be undone.", vbOKCancel, "CV Agreement")

If Answer = vbOK Then

    Sheets("Activities").Select
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("EP2").Select
    Rows("24:24").Select
    Range("C24").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("D20:U20").Select

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can have code that deletes the row of the currently selected cell.

Comment: If you were to remove the item manually, how would you do it (step by step) ?  That is the process which needs to be automated, but there's not enough information in your post to suggest what that should look like.

Comment: Thank you all for looking. I discovered that range names follow the inserted Item no matter what other lines are added to the sheet. This meant that I wrote some code to rename the inserted rows as their own range. After doing this I could write another sub to remove that newly named range when needed.
This may be a very long way around, but it has worked for me thus far.
Thanks again